# Eclipse APT slows compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, apt

I'm currently writing an [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) [APT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/apt/index.html) plug-in to check if my annotations are correct.

But it appears that enabling APT causes my compile process to slow down.
Even saving a tiny, unreferenced class takes a few seconds and eats a lot of memory.

I think the reason is that the APT framework checks a full tree of objects (large project), even though I only need a single class. Just guessing on this one though.

Is there any way for me to improve performance other than disabling APT?

**Edit:** first thing i learned was that APT processing runs in phases and i most likely only need one of them

```
    if (Phase.RECONCILE != Phase.valueOf(env.getOptions().get("phase"))) {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This presentation (zip download of PPT presentation)](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/apt/eclipsecon2007.zip) from the java-apt team gets into some of the issues regarding improving performance.

Comment: that presentation helped me understand what's going on a lot better